# Maintaining Logged in Session

Tags: asp.net

I had a recent interview questions.Wish to share with experts in SO post.Seeking your kind cooperation to clarify few things.

(1) How to maintain user logged in session across web farm.

I had answered as " State Server  ".The interviewer asking the other option.I have answered as "Sql Server".But not quite sure whether it is correct. Would the second option be "Sql Server" ?

(2) You are tasked to configure Custom Single Sign on Authentication Provider? What is the mode would you choose to implement it in Web COnfiguration File?

Would the correct answer be "Form" or can i even choose "Windows"?

(3) How to improve performance of LINQ to SQL Query if Concurrency is not considered?

I have answered as  (i) Set ObjectTrackingEnabled=false and (ii) Turn off OptimisticConcurrency.

Kindly share your answers to understand the things better.Thanks in advance.

Comment: The web farm question is meant to determine whether you know how to manage session across multiple servers. The answer is SQL Server because the state server is limited to a single machine.

Comment: @Josh ,sorry edited it to "Web Farm"

Comment: Funny...I saw your edit and thought I misread, so I edited MY comment!

Answer (score 0):

I'll take a stab at it.

First, as my comment indicated, in a web farm you can't rely on in-memory session management because you can't be certain which server the user's request will hit in a given session. Persisting the session data on a centralized SQL server allows that data to be shared among multiple web servers.

If I understand what you're asking for on the second question, you'd want to use Forms Authentication, possibly with your own membership provider if you're using an external authentication source. To implement in your web.config file, you'll do something like this:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="~/Login" timeout="2880" name=".MYFORMSAUTHCOOKIE" />
</authentication>
<authorization>
  <deny users="?" />
</authorization>
```

You can look up the docs on setting up FormsAuthentication in MSDN.

I'm not a Linq to SQL guy, so I can't help you on the third.